# Bootstrap 3 Modal window with Affix?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im trying to build a modal window with bootstrap 3 that will work as an "ImageViewer" where the user can scroll large images vertically.

On the left side of this ImageViewer, I would like to have small thumbnails of the images affixed so the user always can quickly jump between the images in the gallery. 
I have tried to do this in a simple html page and it works all fine, but as soon as i put the very same html code in a modal window the affix stops working.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <!-- This div container should be affixed when scrolling the images -->
                            <div class="sidebar affix">
                                <a href="#img1">
                                    <img src="//placehold.it/50x50/2255EE/EEE&text=1" alt="" /></a>
                                <a href="#img2">
                                    <img src="//placehold.it/50x50/2255EE/EEE&text=2" alt="" /></a>
                                <a href="#img3">
                                    <img src="//placehold.it/50x50/2255EE/EEE&text=3" alt="" /></a>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-9" role="main">
                            <img id="img1" src="//placehold.it/600x450/2255EE/EEE&text=1" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 5px" alt="" />
                            <img id="img2" src="//placehold.it/600x450/2255EE/EEE&text=2" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 5px" alt="" />
                            <img id="img3" src="//placehold.it/600x450/2255EE/EEE&text=3" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 5px" alt="" />
                            <img id="img3" src="//placehold.it/600x450/2255EE/EEE&text=3" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 5px" alt="" />
                            <img id="img3" src="//placehold.it/600x450/2255EE/EEE&text=3" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 5px" alt="" />
                            <img id="img3" src="//placehold.it/600x450/2255EE/EEE&text=3" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 5px" alt="" />
                            <img id="img3" src="//placehold.it/600x450/2255EE/EEE&text=3" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 5px" alt="" />
                            <img id="img3" src="//placehold.it/600x450/2255EE/EEE&text=3" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 5px" alt="" />
                            <img id="img3" src="//placehold.it/600x450/2255EE/EEE&text=3" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 5px" alt="" />

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

I have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/R8D2v/

Can anyone help out?

Best Regards Niclas

Answer (score 2):

You can set a defined height on the area that you want to be scrollable:

```
    .row{
        height: 600px;
        }
    .col-md-9{
        height:600px;
        overflow-y:scroll;    
    }
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R8D2v/1/

Comment: Hi Kenttam and thanks for your reply, most appreciated!
I tried to add the css as you suggested and sure thing it fixes my problem with the affix not working. However now i have new problem. If a set an explicit height as 600px as in your example and the users browser window is smaller than this hardcoded height, the whole thing looks weird. The pictures go beyond the modal window. I guess i need some soloution working with 100% height. Have played with it but can get that either working... :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't add the class affix manually. The affix function works by toggling the classes .affix, .affix-top, and .affix-bottom as you fulfill the 'data-offset-top' or 'data-offset-bottom' parameters.

Manually assigning the affix class is functionally setting position fixed on the element, which is why when not using a modal it doesn't move. Of course, it will /never/ move because there is no logic to its positioning.

The appropriate affix syntax can be found on the [bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix).

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">...</div>
```

Unfortunately when you are scrolling it is not the document, but rather through the overflow's modal. My guess is affix monitors the former. I created some jquery which mimics the behavior in this [edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8D2v/7/). By inspecting the page you can see that the .affix class is added to .sidebar when you scroll past a point defined in the jquery. I leave it to you to position the element appropriately (use position:fixed).

```
$('.modal').on('scroll', function(){
    var someThreshold = 60;

    if ($('.modal').scrollTop() > someThreshold) {
       $('.modal .sidebar').addClass('affix');
    }
    else {
       $('.modal .sidebar').removeClass('affix');
    }
});
```

On a side note: When posting a fiddle make sure you use 'col-xs-*' as using 'col-md-*' causes the elements to collapse into a single column in the inevitably narrow 'results' pane.

Comment: This switches to fixed position, but it still goes off the page when you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some style for modal.

```
style="position:absolute;overflow:hidden"
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R8D2v/3/)

Comment: Tried this but im not sure were im heading. Could you perahaps edit my fiddle?
Thanks Niclas